# LoadRunner lr_xml_get_values and ORD=All

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

Having a web service soap request that I want to correlate a value in a soap response I use:

```
lr_xml_get_values("XML={response}", "Value=myvalue", "Query=//someplaceinthexmlresponse", LAST);
```

But I wan to save several parameters with the above statement. Is there a way to say

```
"Ord=All" in the lr_xml_get_values function?
```

My soap respons typically exists of 3 nested values I want to save for later correlation.

Using regualt web_custom_request I solved this by saying:

```
web_reg_save_param("helloworld", "LB=<id>", "RB=</id>", Search=Body", "Ord=All", LAST);
```

How can I say `Ord=All`
for a soap request using the lr_xml_get_values function?

Answer (score 0):

```
lr_xml_get_values("XML={response}", 
              "Value=myvalue", 
              "Query=//someplaceinthexmlresponse",
              "SelectAll=yes",
LAST);
```